# Why does ANOVA require balanced data, but mixed-effects models do not?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, unbalanced-classes

Anecdotally, I've often heard it said that unbalanced designs are problematic for ANOVA but not for mixed-effects models. For example, in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78928/repeated-anova-unbalanced-data) someone had unbalanced data (very few observations at the predictor level 'Day 8'), and was planning to do a repeated-measures ANOVA. Then someone else gave this answer:

"I would recommend looking into mixed-effects models (also called random-effects models, multilevel models). They don't require balanced data--i.e., they handle missing data on the dependent variable--so you wouldn't have to drop your Day 8."

The first and third answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24314/when-is-a-repeated-measures-anova-preferred-over-a-mixed-effects-model?rq=1) also make similar statements, without providing an explanation.

Could someone please explain if the reasoning behind such arguments - why are unbalanced data not a problem for mixed-effects models, but they are for ANOVA? And how about ordinary regression?